# Jquery fading effect without hiding other contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a div with class named 'slider' which contains a section(slider-text class) with some header text. There are some divs with images inside the slider class. These divs are used to create a slideshow.

```
<body>
     <div class="slider">
            <section class="slider-text">
                <h1>header</h1>
                <p>Some header text</p>
            </section>
            <div>
                <img src="images/Photography-Camera-HD-Wallpaper1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/Amazing-mountains-in-nature-Big-size-Wallpaper.jpg">
            </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Following css code is used to position the slider-text class absolutely inside slider class. The images are taking the full width of slider class:

```
 .slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98vh;
}
.slider img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98vh;
    }

.slider-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    color: white;
}
```

Following jquery code is used for slider effecet. where one div with image is fading out and another is fading in:

```
$(".slider > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.slider > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next('div')
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slider');
}, 6000);
```

But the problem is while a image div is fading out the text inside 'slider-text' class is also hiding. And it further appearing while next image div is fading in. The header text should not hide while the image divs are fading out/in behind.

Comment: The text should visible between the slider animation efforts , right?

Comment: please provide its final fiddle. I also need this

Comment: please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4y3krkmv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sajjad its not hiding the text, its visible always only the images fading out and in. Just change the text color and check to it.

In css :

```
.slider-text h1,.slider-text p{ z-index:3;}
```

Comment: this is not working. Please provide fiddle for it. I think I'm missing something

Comment: did u change the color of the text Mohtisham

Comment: yap it did getting fading in and out

Comment: I think the issue with the position for your side. just make the position: absolute; for h1 and see. whether its fade out and in..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshBaskaran/jzzbu5fd/1/ see the diff between heading and p tag.. only diff between both is postion:absolute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134835/discussion-between-rajesh-baskaran-and-mohtisham).

Comment: So I can't have paragraph but only header